# services.AddSingleton does not contain a definition for 'value' in Startup.ConfigureServices

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app) on creating a Web API using MongoDB. Everything is working except for injecting my configuration in app startup.

According to the tutorial, I should be setting the following in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>(
        Configuration.GetSection(nameof(BookstoreDatabaseSettings)));

    services.AddSingleton<IBookstoreDatabaseSettings>(sp =>
        sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<BookstoreDatabaseSettings>>().Value);
}
```

But when I paste that into my code, Visual Studio returns the following:

> Error CS1061: 'IOptions' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'IOptions' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)

My `BookstoreDatabaseSettings` class is also copied and pasted from the tutorial:

```
public class BookstoreDatabaseSettings : IBookstoreDatabaseSettings
    {
        public string BooksCollectionName { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IBookstoreDatabaseSettings
    {
        string BooksCollectionName { get; set; }
        string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    }
```

What am I missing here? It seems like I'm just a small syntactical fix away from getting this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are missing a reference to the NuGet package [`Microsoft.Extensions.Options`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/).

Comment: Yup, that did it! Thanks so much!

Comment: It throws an error


'IBookstoreDatabaseSettings' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TOptions' in the generic type or method 'IOptions<TOptions>'

could you help me out please?